# Is there any way to attach a cpp char* buffer(using jni maybe) to an Edittext Widget in Android

Tags: android, c++, kotlin, android-edittext, java-native-interface

When we type text in an EditText widget in Android, the text is stored in the internal Editable object associated with that EditText instance.

My actual application is in cpp and from cpp, I'm calling Kotlin functions using JNI to create my UI.

Now, What I want is to attach a cpp char* buffer with the Edittext object, so that whenever the user types anything in the Edittext, the buffer should get the same text. i.e. it should work similarly to the internal Editable object of the EditText and if I change the buffer content the text in the EditText should be updated.

What I tried so far:
I know that I can attach a TextWatcher with the EditText and update my cpp buffer whenever text is changed, but that would just mean copying the text to my cpp buffer every time. instead, I want that my cpp char* buffer to work similarly to the internal Editable object of the EditText.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Do realize that the Android rendering system is doing a lot of stuff, see youtube video: [Drawn out: How Android renders (Google I/O '18)](https://youtu.be/zdQRIYOST64), so if you need to be so invasive you may have to write your own EditText class, Android is open-source.

Comment: Think about what you are asking here: you want the Android UI thread to constantly be changing the contents of a memory buffer without any synchronization. (eg with a mutex or an atomic swap) This can only end in tears. At least your TextWatcher approach allows you to properly synchronize.